# Word for "gradually removing the vacuum"

Tags: phrase-request, translation, terminology

I'm translating a description of a lyophilization procedure. One of the sentences goes like this, in my translation:

> After keeping the samples in the vacuum for 24 hours, we gradually **relieved** the vacuum, removed the samples from the shelves, and submitted them for subsequent processing.

I picked "relieve" from "vacuum relief valve". Is it okay to say "we gradually **relieved** the vacuum" though? The vacuum is hardly relieved, it is gone.

I found that we can say that we "broke" the vacuum:

> After keeping the samples in the vacuum for 24 hours, we gradually **broke** the vacuum, removed the samples from the shelves, and submitted them for subsequent processing.

But here the word "gradually" may clash with "break". Breaking is usually an abrupt process.

What other word could be used? "We gradually **removed** the vacuum"?

Comment: *broke* seems sudden. I would use "we gradually *released* the vacuum", if it works like releasing air from a balloon.

Comment: I agree with @user3169's suggestion of "release the vacuum". Here is an example of the term in 'real-world' use: [How to release the vacuum in a CRT safely](http://www.edaboard.co.uk/how-to-release-the-vacuum-in-a-crt-safely-t352276.html).

Comment: @user3169 - brilliant, thank you! I thought of using "we gradually restored the pressure" as a makeshift substitute.

Comment: @CowperKettle Yes, *gradually restoring the pressure* also works.

Comment: @Lawrence - it's the "inversion technique" mentioned in any technical translation textbook. (0:

Comment: How about *venting the vacuum* as the opposite of *venting the atmosphere*?

Comment: There's nothing to vent.

Comment: _Relieved_ is spot on. Why do you think it can be improved upon?

Comment: @P.E.Dant - I was unsure. "Trust not your self, but your defects to know make use of every friend - and every foe". ^_^

Comment: Since, as the aphorism has it, "nature abhors a vacuum," it must be imposed and _relieved_ by an agency outside of nature: the experimenter.

Comment: See my Answer below on what ultimately gets rid of a vacuum.

Comment: Physically, you either have a vacuum or you don't, you can't have a little bit of vacuum. You cannot physically "gradually remove a vacuum". You _can_ gradually re-introduce air pressure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go for a post-positioned adverb so that it clearly modifies only **relieved**:

> "...we relieved the vacuum *gradually*, removed the samples quickly,
>   and as fast as humanly possible submitted them for processing"

P.S. **Relieved** is fine. A vacuum that is *broken* is relieved all of a sudden.

Obviously it's the [pot-smoking beatniks and hippies](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=relieve%20the%20vacuum%2Crelease%20the%20vacuum&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crelieve%20the%20vacuum%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crelease%20the%20vacuum%3B%2Cc0) who started saying "release the vacuum".

Answer (score 5):

I would use either: 'We gradually reduced the vacuum' or 'We gradually decreased the vacuum'.

As long as you are not in outer space, vacuum is a drop in air pressure relative to normal air pressure. Reducing or decreasing vacuum implies that you gradually restore your samples to normal air pressure.

Comment: I think 'reduced' is the better option.  'Relieve' has a slight implication that the existence of the vacuum was an undesirable state.

Answer (score 3):

> After keeping the samples in the vacuum for 24 hours, we gradually **relieved** the vacuum, removed the samples from the shelves, and submitted them for subsequent processing.

I'd say "restored atmospheric pressure". Ideally you give a bit more detail. Was ordinary humid air from the room used to bring the pressure up, or dry nitrogen from a tank.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is. You got to think outside the box.

What's in a vacuum? Nothing. Fill the vacuum. Now you have something: oxygen.

"...we gradually filled the vacuum."

Fill. v.

: to make (something) full

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/filled

Answer (score 1):

Using *broke* seems sudden compared to a gradual change.

I would use *release*, for example:

> I *released (gradually let out)* air from a balloon.

So for your example:

> After keeping the samples in the vacuum for 24 hours, we gradually **released** the vacuum, removed the samples from the shelves, and submitted them for subsequent processing.

Comment: But there's nothing to release...  :)

Comment: [*Vacless Safety Vacuum Release Systems SVRS-10ADJ*](https://www.poolsupply4less.com/Vacless-Safety-Vacuum-Release-Systems-SVRS-10ADJ-p/SVRS-10ADJ.htm?gclid=CLenqZOG7M4CFZSIfgodwV0GeA) and [*SR500 Stingl Switch Safety Vacuum Release System*](https://www.poolsupply4less.com/SR500-Stingl-Switch-p/sr-500.htm) for example. It might not make technical sense, but people do say this and understand what it means.

Answer (score 1):

This question requires both knowledge in English language and in physics.

From physics stand point, vacuum doesn't have the characteristics of air, thus it cannot be "released", "broken", "relieved", etc.

*"Vacuum is space void of matter. An approximation to such vacuum is a region with a gaseous pressure much less than atmospheric pressure. Physicists often discuss ideal test results that would occur in a perfect vacuum, which they sometimes simply call "vacuum" or free space, and use the term partial vacuum to refer to an actual imperfect vacuum as one might have in a laboratory or in space. In engineering and applied physics on the other hand, [vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum) refers to any space in which the pressure is lower than atmospheric pressure" - Wikipedia*

So going back to the question I would suggest the following translation:

> After keeping the samples in vacuum for 24 hours, we gradually pressurised them, removed them from the shelves, and submitted them for subsequent processing.

Comment: pressurised them how? By filling the weightless vacuum with some oxygen molecules for weight and to gradually increase the pressure as the force of gravity presses down on more molecules filling up, and more  weight being applied--directly proportional is the increase in force to the increase in the weight.. General science. I studied it, but am I right? Or do I have to dig my HS book out?

Comment: Maybe *repressurized*?

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence, the vacuum can be

> broken

meaning the pressure is increased to atmospheric pressure.

> After keeping the samples in *a* vacuum for 24 hours, we gradually *broke* the vacuum, removed the samples from the shelves, and submitted them for subsequent processing.

In [*Lyophilization of Parenteral*](http://www.fda.gov/ICECI/Inspections/InspectionGuides/ucm074909.htm)

> *Breaking Vacuum* is defined as
>
> Admitting air or a selected gas to an evacuated chamber, while isolated from a vacuum pump, to raise the pressure towards, or up to, atmospheric.

In [White Paper: Recovering Lyophilised Anaerobes](https://www.oxyrase.com/upload/pages/white_paper/white_paper_no.130515_recovering_lyophilized_anaerobes_(1).pdf), in the first paragraph

> At the end of the process the *vacuum is broken*, nitrogen gas replaces the vacuum, and the tubes or vials sealed.

This question uses *break*

> [How can I break the vacuum of a Ultra High Vacuum chamber?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_break_the_vacuum_of_a_Ultra_High_Vacuum_chamber24)

You might also use

> remove

Although your sentence already uses "*removed the samples from the shelves*".
Your sentence might read

> After keeping the samples in *a* vacuum for 24 hours, we gradually *removed* the vacuum, *took* the samples from the shelves, and submitted them for subsequent processing.

or more succinctly

> After keeping the samples in *a* vacuum for 24 hours, we *removed them from the vacuum chamber*, and submitted them for subsequent processing.

by implication, in order to remove the samples from the vacuum chamber, the vacuum would need to be done away with.

Answer (score 1):

While it would seem that there is conventional usage here, if you are uncomfortable with it, the reason is probably that you are attempting to describe what was done to the emptiness of a container rather than what was done to the container.

If you were describing an apple basket that had been emptied of apples and then refilled, you would not say that you removed the emptiness of the basket by adding apples, you would say that you filled the basket with apples. Similarly here you could say that you repressurized the vessel (with ?).

Answer (score 0):

Gradual re-pressurization to normal (or ambient, or 1 atmosphere) would be understood by vacuum chamber folk and everyday folk.  Breaking vacuum is terminology used typically by people dealing with vacuum chambers.  "Removing" something from vacuum would result in virtually instantaneous re-pressurization.  How would one gradually remove something from anywhere.